# Insert list of data into SQL table but got an Error : mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, database

```
sql = """INSERT INTO (Product_details) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
val = [name, Spec ,Ratings ,Delivery ,Discount ,Price ] # list of data into list
```

for values in val:  #loping the variables in the list and adding it to database
engine.execute(sql, values)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Python - Try ? instead of %s - sometimes the parameter marker is not what you would expect it to be so do check which one you need to use for the language you're embedding the SQL in